# rxjs throwing an error once http request returns a specific value

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, polling

I did write an Observable which is polling an URL which completes once a specific value is returned.

```
private checkPairingStatus(paringModel: any): Observable<ResponseObject> {
    let data = { id: 1234 };
    return Observable
        .interval(2000)
        .switchMap(() => this.get<ResponseObject>('http://api/getstatus', data))
        .first(r => r.Status === 'success') // once our pairing is active we emit that
        .timeout(90000, Observable.throw(new Error('Timeout ocurred')));
        // todo: find a way to abort the interval once the PairingStatus hits the 'canceled' status.
}
```

This works pretty fine but I'm struggling on how to throw an exception once my respone for example hits the following status "r.Status === 'canceled'".

Thanks for any hint on that!

Regards
Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `do()` and throw an `Error` with whatever condition you need:

```
return Observable
    .interval(200)
    .do(val => {
        if (val == 5) {
            throw new Error('everything is broken');
        }
    })
    .subscribe(
        val => console.log(val),
        err => console.log('Error:', err.message)
    );
```

This prints to console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Error: everything is broken
```

In your case you'll want to test a condition such as `r.Status === 'canceled'` or whatever.